Widgets in VSCode TreeView
Is there a way to show "widgets" in the side panel of a VSCode extension's TreeView? The default Search and Source Control tabs in the Activity Bar show a TreeView of files, but the search bar and commit messages inputs themselves aren't part of the TreeView (presumably).
My extension needs a simple text input element above the TreeView to filter results (kind of like the search bar). I can't find anything in the Extensions API Documentation, not can I find any 3rd party extensions using these types of widgets.
I don't want to use a webview because I really wanna show files with their structure. Is there any way to do this, or any documentation for this?

I don't think that is possible, but if you write a webview you can use VSCode Elements to make a treeview and get other elements with the correct look.
